# Android : exception handling

Tags: android, exception, httpwebrequest

My android aplication tries to connect to a service using

```
 response = client.execute(getRequest);
```

However the server might be down and at such times I would like to throw a custom `exception` with a custom message, rather than the message android provides, saying the application has shut down unexpectedly.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The thing is my application will inevitably crash when the service it is referring to is down. What I want to do is instead of displaying the message - application failed unexpectedly and crashing....display a message saying server is down,please retry later and allow the application to crash without displaying the default error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using ACRA

http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage

You can overwrite the default crash report and display a custom toast instead using

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey="dGVacG0ydVHnaNHjRjVTUTEtb3FPWGc6MQ",
            mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
            forceCloseDialogAfterToast = false, // optional, default false
            resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
   response = client.execute(getRequest);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // Or add your custom exception here
  Log.e("Your Custom Message:",ex.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the call in a try-catch block, and catch the generic Exception type, then process it (see if the server is down), then throw your custom exception.

```
try
{
   response = client.execute(getRequest);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //processing
   throw new MyCustomException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply
I am actually using a try-catch block already

try {
      // execute the request
      response = client.execute(getRequest);
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
     } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("IO exception", e.toString());
      throw new RuntimeException("Error");
     }

However it still gives me a notfication saying the application has shut down unexpectedly

Comment: Do you process the RuntimeException that you throw in the last catch? Your application will crash whenever there is an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own class `MyException extends Exception{...` and give some custom implementation to it. That can be in the constructor of that class or in some method.

And throw it like -

```
try{
   response = client.execute(getRequest);
}catch(Exception e){
   //handle your exception
   throw new MyException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the `e.printstacktrace();` in exception block?

I think there you will get details on what type of exception you are getting.

Comment: The thing is my application will inevitably crash when the service it is referring to is down. What I want to do is instead of displaying the message - application failed unexpectedly and crashing....display a message saying server is down,please retry later and allow the application to crash without displaying the default error message

Answer (score 0):

If you also wish to show this custom message to the user, you can do so this way:

```
try {
   response = client.execute(getRequest);
} catch(Exception e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My custom message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   throw new Exception("My custom message", e);
}
```